# Modify position of a legend at the top ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Actually my plot looks like this :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/3/1558528424-example1.png

It is a `geom_col` with 4 groups as fill, coord flipped and legend position at top.
I want to modify the legend to make it looks like that :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/21/3/1558528424-example2.png

Basically I think there is 2 steps :

1. Pass the label to the left of the box for 2 of the groups
2. Take 2 of the element and put them under the others 2

But maybe I'm wrong, anyway I can't figure out how to deal with this problem.

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english.